# How to achieve Mac-like use of CTRL and CMD keys on Apple Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, apple-keyboard

I'm very used to emacs-like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to mean "home," and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to mean "select all." Similarly <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> is "end", <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> is "delete", <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does what I expect in Terminal, and probably a few more requisites I don't have on hand.

Of course Ubuntu is a little different. The <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is functionally most paired with the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key, even though in physical keyboard layout the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key will bind to <kbd>super</kbd>.

So my first step was simply swapping <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> by editing xkb since that restores 70% of the functionality I'm missing.

That mostly leaves begin/end/delete and related Mac-"control" functionality, but I don't know a good way to split the functionality or move some super obscure key over to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to achieve this. I'm trying to find a cohesive strategy in general, but hacks are a step.

Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

## For fixing your terminal behaviour:

A straightforward way to achieve what you are trying to do, is to edit your home config files. For a bash terminal, you are looking to edit your `readline` config, which would be your `.inputrc`.

1. Open up a terminal
2. `man readline` This tells you most of your customization options. If you scroll to the bottom, it shows you how emacs mode is configured. More on that below.
3. `gedit .inputrc` This is what you want to edit. It is loaded whenever you log in, and will customize your readline (what bash uses for input) behaviour.

## How I solved a similar issue.

I had to do something similar because I use Vi Mode in Bash:

```
set -o vi
```

- I also use Colemak.
- Subsequently, I use a highly customized version of `Vim`.

My `.vimrc` configuration does not affect `vi` Mode for `bash` (and `ZSH` for that matter).

So I had to create a custom one, and boy was it a lot of work:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~akiva/colemak.vim/trunk/view/head:/.inputrc

You can use my code there as a template to work off of. I have all the functions there. The ones I do not use are commented out. You can map your characters to two things:

```
########
# Copy #
########
# Copy to
"c":    vi-yank-to 
# fake copy line
"C":    "0c$$"
```

- vi-yank-to is a builtin function
- `"0c$$"` is a custom string (Notice the quotes around it) that basically simulates me pressing `0, c, $, $` in that order.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Do you have an alternative for differentiate `ctrl + c` and `cmd + c` in terminal ?
It's my main problem, the first should "cancel" the current line, and the second should copy.

Comment: Go into terminal, and enter `cat` -- now, everything you type is returned to you. Type `ctrl + c` and `cmd + c` to see how how readline recognizes them. `"c":` can be replaced whatever the output brings out, and you can assign `vi-yank-to` to that sequence of characters.

Comment: Using `cat --` and hit <Ctrl+C> the process is killed.
If I map the shortcut to another action (Guake), it will return  `^C` for <Ctrl+C> and same for <Cmd+C>. 
How can I interpret my CMD key, which is mapped to LEFT_CTRL same as my CTRL key, as a different key ?
On OSX, Ctrl is used for all actions related to terminal, same as Linux, and Command is used for copy/paste and other actions related to the application like close a tab, quit terminal ...
How can I reproduce this logic ? I'm not using vim-mode, but if it can help me to solve this problem, I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

This will make you keyboard works like Mac.

Remaps Left Ctrl with AltGr

> sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl

Change the section

> // Map Ctrl to the left Alt key, Alt to the left Win key,
> // and Super to the left Ctrl key.

when it says "replace key " with

> replace key  { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };

Open Tweaks
On Additional Layout Options -> Ctrl , mark "Map Ctrl to the left Alt key, Alt to the left Win key, and Super to the left Ctrl key."

On your shell configuration .zshrc in my case, remap  to intr check if you have the cent symbol there before. Add this to the file :

> stty intr 0xA2

On gnome-terminal remap the copy and paste shortcuts to "Ctrl C" "Ctrl V"

And move physically your keys to make sense